# Reorder text file lines by a specific scheme with bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I need to figure how to reorder in bash a text file , made with another script, composed by lots of lines with a specific scheme. Here's 12 of them.

```
>NODE_3
nucleotide_cov: 170.3683
GC_CONT: 37.00
>NODE_18
nucleotide_cov: 168.8670
GC_CONT: 37.00
>NODE_23
nucleotide_cov: 178.0648
GC_CONT: 35.00
>NODE_41
nucleotide_cov: 174.4054
GC_CONT: 36.00
```

The output needed is:

```
GC_CONT: 37.00  nucleotide_cov: 170.3683    >NODE_3
GC_CONT: 37.00  nucleotide_cov: 168.8670    >NODE_18
GC_CONT: 35.00  nucleotide_cov: 178.0648    >NODE_23
GC_CONT: 36.00  nucleotide_cov: 174.4054    >NODE_41
```

where every column is divided by tab, so "\t" and GC_CONT needs to be the first value of them. 
awk solutions preferred.

**EDIT**

I'll try to more clear. Here's the output file by using

```
awk 'NR%3{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' input.txt 

>NODE_3 nucleotide_cov: 170.3683 GC_CONT: 37.00
>NODE_18 nucleotide_cov: 168.8670 GC_CONT: 37.00
>NODE_23 nucleotide_cov: 178.0648 GC_CONT: 35.00
>NODE_41 nucleotide_cov: 174.4054 GC_CONT: 36.00
```

Good, but i need to format them in order to have "GC_CONT:" at the beginning of every line.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "where every column is divided by tab, so "\t" and GC_CONT needs to be the first value of them. "

Comment: @PierreFrançois see updates on question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chhose one you like:

simple **`awk`** one-liner:

```
awk '/^>/{ n=NR; r=$0; next }{ r=$0 OFS r; if (NR-n==2) print r }' OFS='\t' input.txt
```

---

Or **`awk`** solution for strict order of lines:

```
awk '/^>/{ r1=$0; n=NR }
     n{ if (NR == n+1) r2=$0; else if (NR == n+2) print $0, r2, r1 }' OFS='\t' input.txt
```

The output:

```
GC_CONT: 37.00  nucleotide_cov: 170.3683    >NODE_3
GC_CONT: 37.00  nucleotide_cov: 168.8670    >NODE_18
GC_CONT: 35.00  nucleotide_cov: 178.0648    >NODE_23
GC_CONT: 36.00  nucleotide_cov: 174.4054    >NODE_41
```

Comment: Works properly. Thanks!   Could you please explain how, inside the code, each line is identified as "line 1" "line 2" and "line 3"?  Because last part, the print one, is smooth and easy to understand.

Comment: @Shred, welcome. `print $0, r2, r1` means: print the current record `$0` (i.e. the 3rd line), the second one `r2` and the 1st one `r1`. Also, check my one-liner

Answer (score 2):

Try this awk script:

```
/^>/    {node=$0}
/^nucl/ {nucl=$0}
/^GC/   {print $0 "\t" nucl "\t" node}
```

Or, from command line:

```
awk '/^>/{node=$0} /^nucl/{nucl=$0} /^GC/{print $0 "\t" nucl "\t" node}' input_file
```

Comment: Me too, but @RomanPerekhrest answer was faster and more detailed, cuz he gives also a sample of output, meaning he really understood what I was looking for. Your one was more clean and easy to understand, thanks.

Comment: @Shred: OK, no problem, but a little up vote for my solution also would be appreciated, even if you grant the accepted solution to RomanPerekhrest.

Comment: @Shred: no problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just for information as tagged `sed` :

```
sed -r '/^>/{N;N;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\3\t\2\t\1/g}'
```

Comment: Sed is a very bad solution in computational terms.

Comment: So why have you tagged?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;/\n>/!s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\t\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Collect the lines needed for a record, swapping the lines and replacing the newlines by tabs.

Comment: As said below, sed solutions here are bad.